# What do brackets surrounding function name mean?

Tags: javascript, function

I am looking at someone else's code and trying to understand it. They have a function call name surrounded in parenthesis:

```
myButton.onclick = (myFunction)(a, b, c);
```

Is this different than:

```
myButton.onclick = myFunction(a, b, c);
```

edit:

Just to add more context, the function myFunction has the following form:

```
myFunction = function(a, b, c) {
    return function () {
        // do something with a, b, and c
    }
}
```

Comment: U mean parenthesis right?

Comment: What is invoked will be the return value of the `()` surrounding the function name. Won't have any impact in your example, but may if you're taking the function from an object *(aka a method)*. In that case, the function is disjointed from the object, so the `this` value will be the default value. So `foo.myFunction()` is likely different from `(foo.myFunction)()`.

Comment: Square brackets: `[ ]`, Curly braces/brackets: `{ }`, Angle brackets: `< >`, Parenthesis: `( )`.

Comment: @RyanWH `|` -- or symbol?

Comment: Thanks aaronman, changed to parenthesis.

Comment: @Jim Still makes no difference.

Comment: @Jim: Is the code you're looking at available online?

Comment: @CrazyTrain he has an example in his OP

Comment: @Neal: Yeah, I know. I'd like to see the broader context. I just wonder if the example is being over-simplified.

Comment: I added a basic structure for the function being called. I think I get the idea of what is going on from your explanation, Crazy Train. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no difference.

They do and mean the same thing.